# Is there a way to access data in AsyncStorage inside my Navigator.js file?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

The structure of my app navigation consists of the following:
- Authentication Stack
(SwitchNavigator)
- AppDrawer
   - Profile Screen
   - HomeStack
      - HomeTab
         - HomeScreen
         - SearchScreen

This navigator is exported with createAppContainer() function, which is called as a JSX component inside my App.js file.

I've created a custom header inside my drawer navigation to display the user profile's detail. However, I'm currently not sure how to fetch these data to display inside the my custom profileComponent (profile header) inside my drawer navigator.

Below is the code for my navigator file:

```
const profileComponent = props => (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
      <View style={styles.pictureContainer}></View>
      <Text>NAME GOES HERE</Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </View>
);

const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: {
    screen: WelcomeScreen
  },
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  Register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen
  }
});

const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-chatbubbles" size={27} color={tintColor} />
        )
      }
    },
    SearchScreen: {
      screen: SearchScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name="md-search" size={27} color={tintColor} />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Color.secondary,
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      showLabel: false
    }
  }
);

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Discover: AppTabNavigator
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  }
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStackNavigator,
    User: {
      screen: UserScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: profileComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthStackNavigator,
    HomePage: AppDrawerNavigator
  },
  {initialRouteName: 'Auth'}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can make the profileComponent, a class component. Then you are able to create all the lifecycle methods that a class component can have and then you can easily fetch the user's data from AsyncStorage in componentWillMount(lifecycle method) or constructor.

```
class ProfileComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            userName:""
        }
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        // Fetch user's data here and then call setState().
        let dataFromAsyncStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userName");
        this.setState({userName: dataFromAsyncStorage})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.pictureContainer}></View>
                  <Text>{this.state.userName}</Text>
                </View>
                <DrawerItems {...props} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your suggestions, I've already managed to solve this myself. I've created a function to fetch the user data from Async storage and called this inside my profileComponent class before I return the View.